# Brace initialization of scalars inside an aggregate

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization

Knowing that this is valid c++11

```
int i {1};
```

is this one valid?

```
int j[] {{1}};
```

GCC gives an error, clang a warning.

Comment: unnecessary as you can already do: int j[] = {1,2,3};

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid because `j` is an array of `int` (scalars). You can
only use embedded braces for members which are aggregates themselves.

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct T
{
    int x, y;    
};

int main() 
{
    int j[] {{1}}; // error, int is scalar
    T t[] {{1,2}}; // OK, T is aggregate
}
```